# React function arrow

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I am new to react and arrow function,  I have the following code

```
const users = (props) => {
   return (props.users);
}
```

here is props

```
userDialogs.propTypes = {
   users: Proptypes.array.isRequired
};
```

and this how I use, but it gives me error, map is not function

```
{users.map((username, index) => {
   return <b>{username}</b>
})}
```

Comment: The error says it all. `users` is not an array. Try logging it to see whether it is a valid array or not.

Comment: Can you console.log your variable users, maybe it's not an array

Comment: You assign a _function_ to users, why do you also treat it like an array?

Comment: I updated with more detail on users props.

Answer (score 0):

`.map()` is a function of an Array - but `users` does not contain an Array here. Your code assigns an anonymous function to `users`, so an error is thrown when you try to access its non-existent `map()` function. As long as `props.users` is already an Array, just assign it directly to `users`:

```
const users = props.users;
```

Comment: In console log: (intermediate value).map is not a function

Comment: Interesting, so if you set `users` directly to the value of `props.users`, it does not recognize `map()` as a function of `users`?

Comment: yes, it doesn't

Comment: That suggests `props.users` isn't a valid Array either, then. What kind of data are you seeing if you try logging `props.users` directly?

Answer (score 0):

In the first code block, you're defining an arrow function named `users` which is taking in `props` as a parameter. In order to return something from this function you'll need to **call** the defined function `users` like this:

```js
users(props); // => this returns props.users which is an array
```

Remember that the function `map` is callable only on iterable data structures and the function `users` defined in the first block doesn't have a `map` function. If the returned value `props.users` is an array, calling `map` on the invoked function will work. Like this:

```js
{users(props).map(({username}, index) => {
   return <b>{username}</b>
})}
```